# Compute countif in column Range & combine if with count if

Tags: excel, vba

I have two formulas that I need to transfer to VBA.

On Excel, my formula would be `=countif(A$2:A2,A2)` so I transferred that using this formula but everything is returning to 1. The rows didn't become dynamic and I want only the values to be displayed.

```vb
For a = 2 To lrow
    ws.Range("T" & a).Formula = "=CountIf(A$2&"":""&A2)"",""&A2)"
Next a
```

Next formula that I use in Excel is

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>Q2,"Check","Ok")
```

I tried this formula in VBA:

```vb
For i = 2 to lrow
    If Countif(ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow), "A2") > ws.Range("Q2:Q", & lrow) Then
        ws.Range("T" & i).Value = "Check"
    Else
        ws.Range("T" & i).Value = "Ok"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: `ws.Range("T2:T" & lrow).Formula = "=CountIf(A$2:A2,A2)"` no loop needed

Comment: `ws.Range("S2:S" & lrow).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>Q2,""Check"",""Ok"")"`  Change `S` to the column you want the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could populate column T with your first formula with this line of code:

```
ws.Range("T2:T" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(R2C[-19]:RC[-19],RC[-19])"
```

I can't advise on your second formula unless you clarify where you want to write it...

Comment: Hello! I edited it already. Thank you for your feedback! My excel is still loading but I hope it works. 

Really sorry! I don't know how to use this comments section properly